# Unable to load dynamic library PHP after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, php

I get the following error when trying to use PHP after an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/remctl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/remctl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried [Upgrading to 18.04 caused issue with php installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032475/upgrading-to-18-04-caused-issue-with-php-installation).

When I try to run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php*
```

I get:

```
no matches found: php*
```

I tried to reinstall PHP but this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think problem is in PHP. Problem is module remctl, which cannot be loaded.

If you do not want php-remctl module, I would suggest you just remove the ini file. It is probably in `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/`. By removing the ini file PHP will no longer load that module. See what remctl packages you have installed by typing

```
dpkg -l | grep remctl
```

and maybe you can remove them by typing

sudo apt remove

After you remove the packages that do not work try

```
sudo apt install php-remctl
```

That should install php-remctl package for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Yah i have fix it really problem with php thank u so match